# insert quotes into expression thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a fragment of thymeleaf code with form. I want to validate this form.

```
<form>
<th:block th:fragment="input (label, name, type)">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors(*{__${name}__})}
                            ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
```

Here I got exception:

> Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors(name)" (template: "fragments/inputFieldWithType" - line 5, col 42)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

As I seen in Baeldung, i have to bring field name in quotes like this:

> ${#fields.hasErrors('name')}

So how can I put name param into quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('__${fieldName}__')}"`